# Inserting data using subqueries and Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm a bit new to the whole Python + DB interactions and I have encountered some issues while trying to insert into a table using subqueries. At this point I imagine it's only a problem of syntax/missing parentheses/missing exclamation marks/etc but I can't seem to be able to figure it out by myself so maybe a fresh eye could help with the issue.

This is the query I am trying to run :

```
self.cur.execute("INSERT INTO game_genre (id_game, id_genre) VALUES (( SELECT gd.id_game from game_details gd where gd.title like %s, ( "%" + x + "%" , ))  , (SELECT g.id_genre from genres g where g.title_genre like %s, ("%" + genre + "%",))"))
```

where "x" and "genre" are variables

I have tested the queries independently (outside of the insert) and they return the expected result

Could someone shed some divine light onto this?? Thanks

Comment: Why are you running it as self.cur.execute? I'm not sure it actually has anything to do with whether or not your script will work, but it might

Comment: It's part of a web scraper as I'm processing my items.

Comment: Maybe the documentation regarding string composition might help; I'm not particularly familiar with this package, unfortunately
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to parameterize your query, but you've stuck two different parameter lists into your query as postgres code instead of just one after your query as python code. It's always a good idea to format your code so that the overall structure jumps out at you.

Try:

```
self.cur.execute("""
    INSERT INTO game_genre (id_game, id_genre) 
    VALUES (
        (SELECT gd.id_game FROM game_details gd WHERE gd.title      LIKE %s), 
        (SELECT g.id_genre FROM genres g        WHERE g.title_genre LIKE %s))
""", ("%" + x + "%", "%" + genre + "%"))
```

See http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html for more details on query parameterization. In particular, note that `execute()` takes a query with a bunch of `%s`s, and then a parameter list with one value for each `%s`. Using `"""` around every query is highly recommended, in part for readability, and in part because it will prevent you from having to escape `"` and `'` characters.